# Get all matches within a string using complie and regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to get all matches which starts with `_` and ends with `=` from a URL which looks like

`?_field1=param1,param2,paramX&_field2=param1,param2,paramX`

In that case I'm looking for any instance of `_fieldX=`

A method which I use to get it looks like

```
public static List<String> getAllMatches(String url, String regex) {
    List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?=(" + regex + "))").matcher(url);
    while(m.find()) {
        matches.add(m.group(1));
    }
    return matches;
}
```

called as

`List<String> fieldsList = getAllMatches(url, "_.=");`

but somehow is not finding anything what I have expected.

Any suggestions what I have missed?

Comment: So what is the expected output? I think you need to use a pattern like `_(.*?)=`, or `_.*?=`. You do not need overlapping matches here.

Comment: Why are you passing `"_.="` as regex?

Comment: `.` represents *single* character, but still why do you want to use `(?=..)` in the first place?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yup, that regex works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex like `(?=(_.=))` matches all occurrences of overlapping matches that start with `_`, then have any 1 char (other than a line break char) and then `=`.

You need no overlapping matches in the context of the string you provided.

You may just use a lazy dot matching pattern, [`_(.*?)=`](https://regex101.com/r/FRYMrP/1). Alternatively, you may use a negated character class based regex: [`_([^=]+)=`](https://regex101.com/r/FRYMrP/2) (it will capture into Group 1 any one or more chars other than `=` symbol).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are passing a regex to the method, it seems you want a generic function.

If so, you may use this method:

```
public static List<String> getAllMatches(String url, String start, String end) {
    List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(start + "(.*?)" + end).matcher(url);
    while(m.find()) {
        matches.add(m.group(1));
    }
    return matches;
}
```

and call it as:

```
List<String> fieldsList = getAllMatches(url, "_", "=");
```

Comment: That looks more generic and clear than my method. Thanks for your suggestion.